# What is the difference between use fields attribute and use a FormClass in Django CreateView?

Tags: django, django-views, django-generic-views

What is the difference between use:

```
class FooCreateView(CreateView):
   model = Foo
   fields = (f,o,o)
```

and

```
class FooCreateView(CreateView):
   model = Foo
   form_class = FooForm
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that in the second you need to define a `FooForm` class that must inherit from Django `ModelForm` class and have a `model = Foo`, this mechanism allows you to implement extra validations over your form (i.e. by defining methods like: `def clean_f(self)`, `def clean_o(self)`)

As you can see, you don't need to specify the `fields` attribute in the `CreateView` subclasss if using a form_class, because Django will take the `form_class` fields and use it.

Example:

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Foo(models.Model):
    f = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from appname.models import Foo

class FooForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = '__all__'  # shortcut to add all Foo fields.

    def clean_f(self):
        if 'M' not in self.cleaned_data['f']:
            raise forms.ValidationError('M char must be in f attribute')
        return self.cleaned_data['f']
```

**views.py**

```
from django.views.edit import CreateView
from appname.forms import FooForm

class FooCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Foo
    form_class = FooForm
```

This will raise a ValidationError if you try to save a Foo instance which does not contains a 'M' in their f attribute.

Comment: Complete answer thanks, but if i just want to use the `form_valid` and `form_invalid` methods which one is a best practice, use `fields` or `form_class`? (i know is another question but is too simple to create a new one)

Comment: I think avoiding the `form_class`.

Comment: @slackmart my model field is `start_date` , I have tried defining a function like `def clean_start_date(self):` but the control fails to go inside this function.

Comment: Could you post your model and form classes?